# I can't use useContext Hook with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to make to-do app using TypeScript and Context API, I can't use context of to-dos with useContext Hook.

**Creating Context**,
Here I created an interface of array to-dos and created its context.

```
const todos = [
    { todo: 'Make Break Fast', id: 1, completed: true },
    { todo: 'React Book', id: 2, completed: false },
    { todo: 'Start Coding', id: 3, completed: false },
]


interface ITodos {
    todo: string
    id: number
    completed: boolean
}

export const TodoContext = createContext<ITodos[]>(todos);
```

**Global Provider**,
Here I Created Context Provider and passed its childrens (JSX.Elements) as Props.

```
interface IChildrenProp {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const ContextProvider = ({ children }: IChildrenProp): JSX.Element => {

    return <TodoContext.Provider value={todos}>
        {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
}

export default ContextProvider;
```

**Using Context**,
Here I am expecting my list of to-dos using useCotext Hook from TodoContext.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import TodoContext from './store/context'




const Todo: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {

    const todos = useContext(TodoContext)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>My Todo List</h1>
            <input id='todo' placeholder='e.g. Read Book' />

        </>
    )
}

export default Todo
```

**Error**, But getting following error.

```
TypeScript error in /typescript/todo-app/src/Todo.tsx(9,30):
Argument of type '({ children }: IChildrenProp) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<unknown>'.
  Type '({ children }: IChildrenProp) => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Context<unknown>': Provider, Consumer  TS2345

     7 | const Todo: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
     8 | 
  >  9 |     const todos = useContext(TodoContext)
       |                              ^
    10 | 
    11 | 
    12 |     return (
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the aren't other problems, but explicitly specifying your return type, i.e. `JSX.Element`, and your use of `React.FC` without a type parameter, which results in `React.FC<{}>` is highly problematic. You need to either let type inference do the work for you or specify much more specific and highly elaborated types.

Comment: @Daniel the type can be inferred.

Comment: I organized your code into a sandbox and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-butterfly-rgeyi?file=/src/App.tsx.
Maybe your environment missing something?

Comment: @Daniel, I also tried it by replacing ```React.ReactNode``` with ```JSX.Element```, but it did'nt worked. @Aluan Haddad is right.

Comment: @fiz, yep there is something wrong with the environment. It's working on the codesandbox.